# ComboBox displays duplicate values

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox, .net-4.0

I want to the add the item of `ComboBox`. I has been successful in adding items but the `ComboBox` has **duplicate items**. Why?

**This is my code:**

```
Public Sub load_consigneecode()
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constring)
    con.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "select con_code from TblConsignee order by con_code"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While myreader.Read()
        cmbCode.Items.Add(myreader(0).ToString)
    End While

    myreader.Close()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

**This is the result:**

[image]

**In my table:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub load_consigneecode()
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constring)
    con.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "select con_code from TblConsignee order by con_code"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    'add this in code
    cmbCode.Items.Clear();
    While myreader.Read()
        cmbCode.Items.Add(myreader(0).ToString)
    End While

    myreader.Close()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Else use **distinct** in your SQL query

Answer (score 2):

You are probably not clearing the items in your `ComboBox` before adding new ones:

```
cmbCode.Items.Clear()
```

That said, you are better binding to the `.DataSource` of the `ComboBox` using a `DataTable` and setting the `.DisplayMember` and `.ValueMember` properties.

I would also consider implementing [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement):

> Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. A Using block guarantees the disposal of one or more such resources when your code is finished with them. This makes them available for other code to use.

With the changes you code would look something like this:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Using con As OleDbConnection New OleDbConnection(constring),
      cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [con_code] FROM [TblConsignee] ORDER BY [con_code]", con)
    con.Open()

    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
End Using

cmbCode.DataSource = dt
cmbCode.DisplayMember = "con_code"
cmbCode.ValueMember = "con_code"
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is to make sure that you do not added two times

The second thing I would recomened to do it to:

```
cmbCode.Items.Clear()
```

in the beginning of the function before adding the items